# how to wrap chains around a treasure chest?

Tags: modeling

I've been exploring various methods to wrap chains around a 3D object, particularly a treasure chest, and despite reviewing multiple responses, I remain lost as to what to do. The process so far has been both tedious and imprecise.

Attempting to shape the chains to fit the shape of the chest has proven challenging. When i use curve, it often passes through the box, complicating the task.

Even creating a path curve in Blender to wrap around the box feels confusing.

I would appreciate any help from the community on achieving a more effective and precise way for wrapping chains around a 3D object in Blender.

The image in this post is a reference am using and uploaded it so who's ever reading can get an idea of what am trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could cut some edge loops in *Edit* mode with the knife tool (<kbd>C</kbd> tocut through):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Now select the edge loops, duplicate, separate as new object:

[image]

Then right click > *Convert to > Curve*, then *Curve > Set Spline Type > Bezier*, select the points you want and <kbd>V</kbd> > convert to *Automatic* if you want to smooth the bezier. Keep in mind that you need to cut some segments and join some points because they won't be correctly connected at the intersections:

[image]

Comment: This is a really good solution, and ultimately the use of curves is the best option.  However, in response to the OP, there isn't a perfect one-click solution that I think you're hoping for, and even this answer will likely result in imperfections.  I suggest in scenarios like this taking it one orthographic view at a time and making the small tweaks that it will likely need.

Comment: Yes it will need a lot of adjustments of course

Comment: @moonboots thanks so much for responding  and so far this has been the most clear and concise response i have seen but i wanted to ask i how do i attach the chains to the loops? i have seen videos where you need to add an array, then fit to curve, and add an empty? or do i need to just draw the chains to the cuts and then it takes the shape?  am still a complete beginner learning sorry for all the noob questions

Comment: Yes use the Array and Curve modifiers, the Curve modifier will deform some links though, you'll replace them

Comment: @moonboots ohh okay i get it now it creates a link for the chains to follow ! going to try it out then post results thx!